# how do I use 3rd party modules in python 3.0

Tags: python, python-3.x, module

Guys here is the link from where I downloaded a module and I installed it to my PyCharm. But there is no much documentation about the module like how to use it, what functions it has etc.,

Can someone explain me that module??

link: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/windowsprefetch/1.0.7

Answer (score 0):

There's a link to the source repository on the pypi page - https://github.com/PoorBillionaire/Windows-Prefetch-Parser.

You can take a look there to see if desired documentation exists, else you could always check the code and see what it does.